# window.onbeforeunload and window.location.href in IE

Tags: html, window.location

We are using window.location.href to navigate the user to a page.
Also, we have configured the window.onbeforeunload event to alert users in case there are any unsaved changes.

```
window.onbeforeunload = confirmBeforeClose;

function confirmBeforeClose() {
    if (jwd.global.inEditMode)
        return "Your changes will not be saved :) and you will be punished to death";
}
```

In places where there are unsaved changes, and I try to use `window.location.href` to navigate the user, I get the alert message.

It works fine if I click OK on the popup. However, if I click CANCEL, the JS throws an unspecified error at window.location.href.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please show the code where you are doing the `location.href`.

Comment: I can only reproduce this in IE7.  I confirmed that FF 3.6, Chrome 4, and IE8 do not throw an error (did not test IE6). Please add IE7 as part of the question or title.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I was also experiencing this issue (in IE7 and above, not in IE6 however).

The only solution that I could find was wrapping the window.location.href call in a try/catch block.

The below is a complete example that reproduces the problem. If you uncomment out the try/catch then it works as desired in all browsers.

JavaScript (in HTML head):

```
  window.onbeforeunload = confirmBeforeClose;

  function confirmBeforeClose( )
  {
    return 'You have made changes on this page that will be lost if you navigate away without saving.';
  }

  function leavePage( )
  {
     // try {
          window.location.href = "http://www.example.com";
     // } catch( e ) { }
  }
```

HTML:

```
<body>
 <a href="#" onclick="leavePage(); return false;">Leave this page</a> 
</body>
```

Comment: For future visitors: This just fixed it for me on IE9 now as well, so it's clearly not IE7 only.

Comment: ...and for IE11 as well!

Comment: This works for me `window.location.href` but `window.location` doesn't.